# Quering F5 BIG IPs HSQL database

Tags: hsqldb, f5

I recently came across the guishell utility of the F5 Bigip devices.The guishell opens a HSQL prompt.Would anybody know how to find the name of all the tables that can be queried within the F5 Bigip system ?

Answer (score 0):

The list of tables in an HSQLDB database can be queries from INFORMATION_SCHEMA

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

This list also shows the names of other tables in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA, which can be queries for the list of columns and other objects.